Modifying some features on the booking add-on to my WordPress site
i want to add a booking service in my wordpress website.
I searched for some plugins and found the best one is Booking Press.
I need the user to write his phone number so that he will receive a confirmation message for his reservation
And i want to receive the booking data to admin whatsApp Number ? can i do that with Booking Press Plugin?
